# Differentiation of $x^{{x}^{{x}^{...}}}$

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

All of us experienced with this function :
$$x^{x}$$
It's easy to differentiate it, so my question is:
How to differentiate this function:
 $$x^{{x}^{...}}$$, maybe there is some recurrence equation?
For example there is $n$, $x$ in "stairs".
P.S. sorry for my English skills

Answer (score 6):

Note that if $f(x) = x^{x^{x^{\cdots}}}$, we then have
$$f(x) = x^{f(x)}$$
Taking the logarithm on both sides, we obtain
$$\log(f(x)) = f(x) \log(x)$$
Differentiating we obtain
$$\dfrac{f'(x)}{f(x)} = f'(x) \log(x) + \dfrac{f(x)}x$$
Now obtain $f'(x)$.

---

If it is a finite stair, define $f_0(x) = x$, $f_1(x) = x^x$ and in general $f_{n+1}(x) = x^{f_n(x)}$, where $f_n(x)$ has $n$ $x$'s in the exponent. We can now compute the derivative inductively, taking the logarithm on both sides, we have
$$\log\left(f_{n+1}(x) \right) = f_n(x) \log(x) \implies \dfrac{f_{n+1}'(x)}{f_{n+1}(x)} = f_n'(x) \log(x) + \dfrac{f_n(x)}x$$
Hence, we have
$$f_{n+1}'(x) = f_{n+1}f_n'(x)\log(x) + \dfrac{f_{n+1}(x)f_n(x)}x$$
where we have $f_0'(x) = 1$, $f_1'(x) = x^x(1+\log(x))$.

Comment: I asked about finite "stair". So is that normal that : $f(x) = x^{f(x)}$ in first equation?

Comment: Amazing , thanks a lot your all !